# Node url.format method without decoding querystring

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am parsing url with url.parse() and adding query to it, but when i format using url.format(), it encodes my query parameters and replace "+" with encoded value, is there any way to keep encoding in just url params

```
const parsedUrl = url.parse('localhost://0.0.0.0/products', true);
parsedUrl.query = { query: 'foo+bar' };
return url.format(parsedUrl);
```

Comment: `+` is used as substitute for a space for content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you want a literal `+` then you have to encode it.

Comment: how? + gets encoded back with url.format method

Comment: Because `url` treats it as a literal `+` and therefor encodes it as such. If that `+` in `query` should be a space then use a space and not a `+`

Comment: i want query to have literal "+" like localhost://0.0.0.0/products?query=foo+bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node --version
v10.19.0
node
> const url=require('url')
undefined
> url.parse('localhost://0.0.0.0/products?query=foo+bar').query.split('=')[1]
'foo+bar'
```